# PHP Explode multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I have multiple arrays which I'm trying to explode and divide all information inside. For some reason, I'm losing the information about main arrays when I do that.

Arrays

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30
    [1] => 2020-12-01 / 2020-12-31
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30
    [1] => 2020-12-01 / 2020-12-31
    )
```

I used the following code:

```
foreach ($list as $line) {
    foreach ($line as $text) {
        $parts[] = explode(' / ', $text);
    }
}
```

print_r($parts) will return the following:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-11-01
    [1] => 2020-11-30
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-01
    [1] => 2020-12-31
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-11-01
    [1] => 2020-11-30
    )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-01
    [1] => 2020-12-31
    )
```

but this is unfortunately not what I'm looking for, what I need is this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-11-01
        [1] => 2020-11-30
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-31
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-11-01
        [1] => 2020-11-30
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-31
        )
    )
```

I searched all around but did not find an easy way for that. hope somebody can help. thank you!

Comment: what is `$z` variable?

Comment: that was a mistake, sorry. already fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with a nested [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to explode the data in each value:

```
$data = array(
  array(
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
  ),
  array(
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
  )
);

$result = array_map(function ($a) { 
    return array_map(function ($v) { 
        return explode(' / ', $v ); 
    }, $a); 
}, $data);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new array instead of writing in the same indices that you are exploding, which you would do like this:

```php
$arr = [
    0 => [
        0 => '2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30',
        1 => '2020-12-01 / 2020-12-31',
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => '2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30',
        1 => '2020-12-01 / 2020-12-31',
    ]
];


foreach ($arr as $bulkIndex => $bulks) {
    foreach ($bulks as $lineIndex => $line) {
        $arr[$bulkIndex][$lineIndex] = explode(' / ', $line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want keep your original array intact. A solution is use another array to put your exploded array inside:

```
<?php

$list = [
  [
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
  ],
  [
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
    "2020-11-01 / 2020-11-30",
  ]
];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($list as $line) {
  $parts = [];
  foreach ($line as $text) {
      $parts[] = explode(' / ', $text);
  }
  $newArray[] = $parts;
}
var_dump($newArray);

/*
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2020-11-01' (length=10)
          1 => string '2020-11-30' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2020-11-01' (length=10)
          1 => string '2020-11-30' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2020-11-01' (length=10)
          1 => string '2020-11-30' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2020-11-01' (length=10)
          1 => string '2020-11-30' (length=10)
*/
```